# Eigenvector and eigenvalue properties: PSD matrices $K$ and $K + \sigma I$

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two Positive Semi-Definite (PSD) matrices, $K_1$ and $K_2 = K_1 + \sigma I$. For $K_1$, I do eigen decomposition, I get the eigenvector matrix $V$ and diagonal eigenvalue matrix $D$, which hold: $K_1 = VDV^T$.

So, for $K_2$, it has the same eigenvector matrix: $V$ and its eigenvalue matrix is: $D + \sigma I$.

My question is how to proof: $K_2$ has such eigenvector and eigenvalue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $K_1 = V D V^T$, write $K_2 = V D V^T + \sigma I = V D V^T + \sigma V I V^T = V (D + \sigma I) V^T$. Hence  $K_2$ has eigenvalues $(D + \sigma I)$.